# Mantra of Retribution vs Conviction

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I'm wondering which of these to take on my lvl 60 monk who's currently farming Act 1 of Inferno (killed the Butcher). I could take MoR with the Transgression rune for the nice bonus to attack speed, or MoC with Reclamation for some more life on hit.

More details on my build:

- dual-wield/APS/life-on-hit build with 2 swords
- Armor 4948
- DPS ~14000
- Atks/sec 2.25
- 33.6k life
- 410 life on hit

Answer (score 3):

You should try Conviction/Overaw, and spam it every 3 seconds when you want to burst your damage.  You and everyone in your group will do 48% additional damage, which is a ton, relative to what alternatives can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are "farming" Act I of Inferno, it doesn't sound like you need the additional life on hit, not to mention that increasing your attack speed will therefore increase the amount of life you are reclaiming per second.

It appears more worthwhile to go with Transgression, since you will achieve both higher DPS and higher life on hit.